# AWS Lambda logging through Serilog UDP sink and logstash silently fails

Tags: aws-lambda, logstash, serilog

We have a .NET Core 2.1 AWS Lambda that I'm trying to hook into our existing logging system.

I'm trying to log through Serilog using a UDP sink to our logstash instance for ingestion into our ElasticSearch logging database that is hosted on a private VPC. Running locally through a console logs fine, both to the console itself and through UDP into Elastic. However, when it runs as a lambda, it only logs to the console (i.e CloudWatch), and doesn't output anything indicating that anything is wrong. Possibly because UDP is stateless?

NuGet packages and versions:

- Serilog 2.7.1
- Serilog.Sinks.Udp 5.0.1

Here is the logging code we're using:

```
        public static void Configure(string udpHost, int udpPort, string environment)
        {
            var udpFormatter = new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true);

            var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("applicationName", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("applicationVersion", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString())
                .Enrich.WithProperty("tags", environment);

                loggerConfig
                    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Level:u}]: {Message}{N---ewLine}{Exception}")
                    .WriteTo.Udp(udpHost, udpPort, udpFormatter);

              var logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
              Serilog.Log.Logger = logger;
              Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);
        }
```

```
          // this is output in the console from the lambda, but doesn't appear in the Database from the lambda
          // when run locally, appears in both
          Serilog.Log.Logger.Information("Hello from Serilog!");
          ...
          // at end of lambda
          Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

And here is our UDP input on logstash:

```
     udp {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
         port => 5000
         tags => [ 'systest', 'serilog-nested' ]                                                                                                                                                                                              
         codec => json                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     }
```

Does anyone know how I might go about resolving this? Or even just seeing what specifically is wrong so that I can start to find a solution.

Things tried so far include:

- Pinging logstash from the lambda - impossible, lambda doesn't have ICMP
- Various things to try and get the UDP sink to output errors, as seen above, various attempts at that. Even putting in a completely fake address yields no error though
- Adding the lambda to a VPC where I know logging is possible from
- Sleeping around at the end of the lambda. SO that the logs have time to go through before the lambda exits
- Checking the logstash logs to see if anything looks odd. It doesn't really. And the fact that local runs get through fine makes me think it's not that.
- Using UDP directly. It doesn't seem to reach the server. I'm not sure if that's connectivity issues or just UDP itself from a lambda.
- Lots of cursing and swearing

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use another solution to get the log events from the Lambda into Elastic, or are you fixed on using the UDP sink? Not that the sink is bad (I'm the author of it), but my experience with Lambdas is that it is better if they don't reside in a VPC, and that wouldn't be possible if you are intent on sending the log event using either HTTP or UDP.

Comment: Yeah I'd setup a log subscription and fire it into ES, at least that's the way we do it nodejs - just make sure you ONLY output JSON, any spaces or TEST {...JSON object} will mean ES won't index it

Comment: @FantasticFiasco: Our ES instance isn't exposed on the public internet for good reasons, so I think going to it directly would also mean we have to go on the VPC. So avoiding UDP isn't going to get us around that unfortunately. Thanks though. And we do use your sink in various places successfully (console apps on boxes, etc) so we were hoping to use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues helped me get most of the way there, and then I managed to figure out the last bit.

- I updated Serilog.Sinks.Udp to 6.0.0
- I updated the UDP setup code to use the AddressFamily.InterNetwork specifier, which I don't believe was available in 5.0.1.
- I removed enriching our log messages with "tags", since I believe it being present on the UDP endpoint somehow caused some kind of clash and I've seen it stop logging without a trace before.

And voila!

Here's the new logging setup code:

```
loggerConfig
    .WriteTo.Udp(udpHost, udpPort, AddressFamily.InterNetwork, udpFormatter)
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Level:u}]: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}");
```

Answer (score 0):

In line with my comment above you can create a log subscription and stream to ES like so, I'm aware that this is NodeJS so it's not quite the right answer but you might be able to figure it out from here:

```
/* eslint-disable */
// Eslint disabled as this is adapted AWS code.

const zlib = require('zlib')
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const elasticsearch = new Client({ ES_CLUSTER_DETAILS })
/**
 * This is an example function to stream CloudWatch logs to ElasticSearch.
 * @param event
 * @param context
 * @param callback
 */
export default (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true

    const payload = new Buffer(event.awslogs.data, 'base64')

    zlib.gunzip(payload, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            return callback(null, err)
        }

        const logObject = JSON.parse(result.toString('utf8'))

        const elasticsearchBulkData = transform(logObject)

        const params = { body: [] }
        params.body.push(elasticsearchBulkData)

        esClient.bulk(params, (err, resp) => {

            if (err) {
        callback(null, 'success')
        return
    }

        })

        callback(null, 'success')
    })
}

function transform(payload) {
    if (payload.messageType === 'CONTROL_MESSAGE') {
        return null
    }

    let bulkRequestBody = ''

    payload.logEvents.forEach((logEvent) => {
        const timestamp = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp)

        // index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
        const indexName = [
            `cwl-${process.env.NODE_ENV}-${timestamp.getUTCFullYear()}`,              // year
            (`0${timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1}`).slice(-2),  // month
            (`0${timestamp.getUTCDate()}`).slice(-2),          // day
        ].join('.')

        const source = buildSource(logEvent.message, logEvent.extractedFields)
        source['@id'] = logEvent.id
        source['@timestamp'] = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp).toISOString()
        source['@message'] = logEvent.message
        source['@owner'] = payload.owner
        source['@log_group'] = payload.logGroup
        source['@log_stream'] = payload.logStream

        const action = { index: {} }
        action.index._index = indexName
        action.index._type = 'lambdaLogs'
        action.index._id = logEvent.id

        bulkRequestBody += `${[
            JSON.stringify(action),
            JSON.stringify(source),
        ].join('\n')}\n`
    })
    return bulkRequestBody
}

function buildSource(message, extractedFields) {
    if (extractedFields) {
        const source = {}

        for (const key in extractedFields) {
            if (extractedFields.hasOwnProperty(key) && extractedFields[key]) {
                const value = extractedFields[key]

                if (isNumeric(value)) {
                    source[key] = 1 * value
                    continue
                }

                const jsonSubString = extractJson(value)
                if (jsonSubString !== null) {
                    source[`$${key}`] = JSON.parse(jsonSubString)
                }

                source[key] = value
            }
        }
        return source
    }

    const jsonSubString = extractJson(message)
    if (jsonSubString !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(jsonSubString)
    }

    return {}
}

function extractJson(message) {
    const jsonStart = message.indexOf('{')
    if (jsonStart < 0) return null
    const jsonSubString = message.substring(jsonStart)
    return isValidJson(jsonSubString) ? jsonSubString : null
}

function isValidJson(message) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(message)
    } catch (e) { return false }
    return true
}

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)
}
```

Comment: I don't think going direct to our Elastic with custom logic to format the messages is going to fly here, it even feels a bit loose to me, it would mean our log formatting and processing code exists in two places rather than one (i.e this custom code here and then the actual logstash configuration). So I don't think this'll work for us. But thank you

Comment: Ahh OK gotcha, I understand, sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: No worries, don't get me wrong, I appreciate the help! Thanks for taking the time.